# Unexpected Flutter linter warning: depend_on_referenced_packages

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-lints

After I recently upgraded flutter to 3.0.0 and flutter_lints to 2.0.1, I started getting the following warning:

```
Depend on referenced packages.
```

Here, the dependency that is imported is defined in the pubspec.yaml of another module that the current module already depends on. In other words, the dependency flow is as follows:

```
A (module that gives warning and imports D) -> B -> D
```

I don't understand why I see this warning. Just because module A doesn't directly depend on library D? What should I do with this warning? How can I eliminate it without ignoring the rule in analysis_options.yaml file?

Comment: You can suppress rules for files or lines of code explained in the [static analysis guide](https://dart.dev/guides/language/analysis-options#suppressing-rules-for-a-file).

Comment: @MerlinAttilaFejzuli yep, I'm aware of it. However, I don't believe I should see this warning in the first place.

Answer (score 3):

Had the same warning.

In my case it was caused by flutter_localizations.

I realized I put

```
flutter_localizations:
    sdk: flutter
```

below dev_dependencies and not below dependencies in pubspec.yaml.

Maybe you have the same or similar problem.

Comment: My ```local_auth: ^2.1.0``` also gives this warning. It is in dependencies, instead of dev_dependencies. So strange.

Answer (score 2):

This error recommends that in `pubspec.yaml` file, you add the package in the dev-dependencies or dependencies(depending on the use case as instructed on the package docs). Checkout [this](https://dart-lang.github.io/linter/lints/depend_on_referenced_packages.html)

[image]

Also, make sure you are importing the right package in the right format as required to in the package documentation.

Answer (score 2):

Check to make sure the package is under "dependencies" and not (for example) under "dev_dependencies"

Comment: D'Oh! Exactly where I had mine.

Answer (score 1):

You're seeing the intended behavior of that lint. Without that lint you would get an error if the included library was not depended upon, and you rightly assume that a transitive dependency is enough to build.

The lint is likely here to protect against the cases where a dependency has either removed the dependency or changed to a version with breaking changes, such that your transitive use would either break or unintentionally change.

Each of the lints contain a brief [description](https://dart.dev/tools/linter-rules#depend_on_referenced_packages) of why they exists.

Comment: No, this lint `depend_on_referenced_packages` warns about used imports that do not have a corresponding entry in the pubspec file.
"Depend on" means to have it in your pubspec.yaml `dependencies:` section.

Comment: I was wrong, you are right!

Answer (score 1):

In my case, they were all packages that were required (and thus included) by other packages that were listed in pubspec.yaml but since I was using them myself directly, I had to explicitly add them to pubspec.yaml as direct-dependents.

Once I added the offending packages to pubspec.yaml, error was gone.

Answer (score 0):

analysis_options.yaml

```
include: package:flutter_lints/flutter.yaml

# Additional information about this file can be found at
# https://dart.dev/guides/language/analysis-options

linter:
  rules:
    depend_on_referenced_packages: false
```

Comment: This is not a solution. This is suppression. I'm trying to understand why I'm seeing this warning.

Answer (score 0):

I had all the records in pubspec.yaml
In my case it was caused by the Android Studio itself. I had to restart it
and all was started to work fine